# Client websocket connection through tor

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket, proxy, tor

There is a websites on the internet which uses a websocket to update its values. What I would like to do is, I would like to connect to that websocket in such a way that I receive the updates instead of making a lot of get requests... .

- This already works !

But now i would like to do this more anonymous.
(E.g. by adding TOR between me (the client) and the server)).

Is this possible? And how?

The code which +/- works

```
from websocket import create_connection
import json
import time

headers = json.dumps({'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
                        'Accept-Language': 'nl-BE,nl-NL;q=0.9,nl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.6',
                        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
                        'Connection': 'Upgrade',
                        ...
                        'Sec-WebSocket-Extensions': 'permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits',
                        'Sec-WebSocket-Key': 'TiMSmtLKCoev5n/rbl3h4g==',
                        'Sec-WebSocket-Version': '13',
                        'Upgrade': 'websocket'
                        })

msg_a = {'Id': 'c729860f-0565-7dfc-65ca-b83880446c3e',
         'TTL': 10,
         'MessageType': 1,
         'Message': '{"NodeType":1,"..."'}


msg_b = {'Id': '7674a2be-bec9-267b-0cbf-f54a3250bb5d',
         'TTL': 10,
         'MessageType': 1000,
         'Message': '{"...."'}

    
ws = create_connection('wss://wss01......be/',headers=headers)


ws.send(json.dumps(msg_a).encode())

while True:
    print(ws.recv())
    ws.send(json.dumps(msg_b).encode())
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. There is a [library](https://pypi.org/project/tor/) built for this very purpose. You can read up on its documentation or even try another library, there have already been many made for use in python.

Comment: did you've ever used that library? it doesn't look trustworthy.

Comment: There are of course, many other libraries that do the same thing. That was the first one that came up when I searched. You can find other ones that may seem better for you.